# How to dump the screen programmatically?

Tags: android

Is there way to dump the current screen to a bitmap in Android?

And what about dump screen of other applications? For example, running a service background, the foreground app could send an intent to start the service, and capture the current screen and save as a bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code at [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5bab2668cd5ab44f/efd2e7cfd14e4b16?lnk=gst&q=yahoo#efd2e7cfd14e4b16).

2nd result for Google: *android screen capture code*.

Comment: Thanks mcandre, but is there any way using an Android application to do this?

Comment: Do you want an app to take screenshots (there are many), or as you asked in the title, do you want code to take screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to take screenshots via an Android application.

The only way you can do it is via DDMS in the Android SDK when connected to your computer in debug mode.

There are apps available to take screenshots, but they only work on root devices.